# Spring cloud Stream function not recognized

Tags: migration, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-function, java-20

I have a Spring Boot Kafka streaming application.
**After upgrading to SB3**, the spring.cloud.function.definition is not recognized anymore.

I enabled debug logs and was of help.
I see these messages in logs:

```
Multiple functional beans were found [myEvents, sendToDlqAndContinue], thus can't determine default function definition. Please use 'spring.cloud.function.definition' property to explicitly define it.
```

This is my `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: @project.artifactId@
  cloud:
    config:
      name: my-app
    stream:
      default:
        producer:
          useNativeEncoding: true
      function:
        definition:myEvents
        ineligible-definitions: sendToDlqAndContinue
```

These are the dependencies I have:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </parent>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have tried debugging the Cloud stream Kafka classe which is reporting the error, [BeanFactoryAwareFuntionRegistry.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/main/spring-cloud-function-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/context/catalog/BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry.java#L132)

and found that
`this.applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty(FunctionProperties.FUNCTION_DEFINITION, "");` is ""

It does contain `ineligible-definitions` I have in yml, but not the `definition`

Any clues are highly appreciated. Maybe there are some changes in SpringBoot 3 related to cloud streams? Any missing dependency?

**Update**

I tried to run the app after adding the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

The application now consumes messages, but the dependency does not log the unsupported or migrated properties. How can I know which property is removed/migrated??

I find no official documentation about changes in new release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was changed `spring.cloud.stream.function` to `spring.cloud.function`, it works for me.

TO-BE `application.yml`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: @project.artifactId@
  cloud:
    config:
      name: my-app
    function:
      definition:myEvents
      ineligible-definitions: sendToDlqAndContinue
    stream:
      default:
        producer:
          useNativeEncoding: true
```

But, [Official Document](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_overview) says both of configuration works.

> To specify which functional bean to bind to the external destination(s) exposed by the bindings, you must provide spring.cloud.stream.function.definition or native to spring-cloud-function spring.cloud.function.definition property.

And, you should be check this [url](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2704#issuecomment-1615248727), it works for me.

I changed `class` to `function`.

I hope this helps.